# Seperate a Column with multiple lines from a csv file and order them in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a csv file where I need to find the best Team according to their best 11 Players with Python. My Problem is the Column with the Player Name and the Team is in the same Box separated with 1 l empty line. If I open the .csv file it looks like this:

```
,Rating_x,Player,Rating_y,
8.32,"Didier Drogba

Chelsea, 42, FW",7.55
```

How can I create this .csv into this:

```
,Rating_x,Player,Team,Age,Position,Rating_y,
8.32,Didier Drogba,Chelsea, 42, FW,7.55
```

So I can order them to their teams and make a General Ranking.

Comment: Unless there's some more formatting, it's going to be very hard to separate the player name from the team. For example, you cannot in general just take the first two space-separated terms for the name. Otherwise you'd parse names like "Konrad de la Fuente" incorrectly. And you can't take the last term to be the team, because you'd parse "Paris Saint Germain" incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want a comma-separated list to be converted into cells in a column? Follow the steps below (From: https://www.adinstruments.com/support/knowledge-base/how-can-comma-separated-list-be-converted-cells-column-lt)

1. Highlight the column that contains your list.
2. Go to Data > Text to Columns.
3. Choose Delimited. Click Next.
4. Choose Comma. Click Next.
5. Choose General or Text, whichever you prefer.
6. Leave Destination as is, or choose another column. Click Finish.

With python:

```
series.str.split(',', expand=True)
```

Comment: This question is asking about using Python and Pandas to do this. Your answer is not going to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by doing:

```
import pandas as pd
enter code here
df[['Name','TAP']] = df.Player.str.split("\n\n", expand=True)
del df['Unnamed: 0']
del df['Player']
df[['Team','AGE','POS']] = df.TAP.str.split(", ", expand=True)
del df['TAP']
```